# Kendu UI Grid Angular (12)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Working on an angular (12) app and there one component that uses Kendo UI grid with similar definition:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
 ....
[filter]="gridConfig.state.filter"
>
<kendo-grid-column field="someField" [title]="SomeTitle">
          <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate 
            let-filter 
            let-column="column" 
            let-filterService="filterService">
            <kendo-grid-numeric-filter-menu [column]="column"
                                            [filter]="filter"
                                            [filterService]="filterService"
                                            [extra]="false">
            </kendo-grid-numeric-filter-menu>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
         ....
</kendo-grid>
```

It works fine, but have found an issue, when I pre select values ( on component loading get from parameters columnName and value ) in component.ts file , as  this.grid.filters = { logic: "and", filters: [...]} and also as this.gridConfig.state.filter = { logic: "and", filters: [...]} , where filters has correct structure ( checked it console ) like

```
{
          logic: "and",
          filters: [
            {
              logic: "or",
              filters: [
                {
                  field: fieldName,
                  operator: "startswith",
                  value: "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        };
```

and setup them to gridConfig ( also have tried assign the same to grid.filter ) after the grid do the actual filtering the filter themself is not contain any filter's values and it's not selected.  Seems that it's not correct way to select filter's values from .ts ? Also think that it can be done somehow with filterService that is used to provide filtering, but there are not a lot of documentation about how it relate to kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate and what is more interesting it's setup values to UI filter component and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that solution and controls are working fine and it's only inaccurate parameters processing. The reason was that filters are case-sensitive!